# generating two orthogonal vectors that are orthogonal to a particular direction

Tags: arrays, numpy, vector, orthogonal, cross-product

What is the simplest and most efficient ways in numpy to generate two orthonormal vectors a and b such that the cross product of the two vectors equals another unit vector k, which is already known?

I know there are infinitely many such pairs, and it doesn't matter to me which pairs I get as long as the conditions axb=k and a.b=0 are satisfied.

Comment: `a` and `b` are shape (3,) (1d with 3 elements)?  How would you do this 'by hand'?

Comment: yes. a, b and k are all of shape(3,). I know how to do it by hand. I have 5 equations in 6 unknowns, does it mean there are no simple ways (with just a few lines) and I have to use numerical methods in scipy in solve it?

Comment: I was thinking of algebraic versions of the cross and dot products in the accepted answer.  For small arrays those would be just as fast.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) procedure will do exactly this. For example:

```
>>> k  # an arbitrary unit vector k is not array. k is must be numpy class. np.array
np.array([ 0.59500984,  0.09655469, -0.79789754])
```

To obtain the 1st one:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(3)  # take a random vector
>>> x -= x.dot(k) * k       # make it orthogonal to k
>>> x /= np.linalg.norm(x)  # normalize it
```

To obtain the 2nd one:

```
>>> y = np.cross(k, x)      # cross product with k
```

and to verify:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(x), np.linalg.norm(y)
(1.0, 1.0)
>>> np.cross(x, y)          # same as k
array([ 0.59500984,  0.09655469, -0.79789754])
>>> np.dot(x, y)            # and they are orthogonal
-1.3877787807814457e-17
>>> np.dot(x, k)
-1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> np.dot(y, k)
0.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work where k is different vector

```
>>> k = np.array([ 0.0,  0.0215, -1.334])
>>> x = np.random.randn(3)
>>> x -= x.dot(k) * k
>>> x /= np.linalg.norm(x)
>>> np.dot(x, k)
0.38532052441276377
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, together with René Wirnata answer below this works even if the first input vector is NOT a unit vector.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry, I can't put it as a comment because of a lack of reputation.

Regarding @behzad.nouri's answer, note that if `k` is not a unit vector the code will not give an orthogonal vector anymore!

The correct and general way to do so is to subtract the longitudinal part of the random vector. The general formula for this is 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLiF3.gif)

So you simply have to replace this in the original code:

```
>>> x -= x.dot(k) * k / np.linalg.norm(k)**2
```

Comment: This method is called as [Gram-Schmidt Process](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmdl/LessonPlans/Lesson10.pdf)

Comment: So this does work in both cases, whether k is a unit vector or not, right ?

Comment: Well yes, it does

Answer (score 1):

Assume the vector that supports the orthogonal basis is u.

```
b1 = np.cross(u, [1, 0, 0])   # [1, 0, 0] can be replaced by other vectors, just get a vector orthogonal to u
b2 = np.cross(u, b1)
b1, b2 = b1 / np.linalg.norm(b1), b2 / np.linalg.norm(b2)
```

A shorter answer if you like.

Get a transformation matrix

```
B = np.array([b1, b2])
TransB = np.dot(B.T, B)
u2b = TransB.dot(u) # should be like [0, 0, 0]
```